# Finding amortized time complexity

Tags: c++, time, amortized-analysis

So I wrote a function `push_back` for a vector class, and I'm now trying to figure out the amortized time complexity. I'm pretty new to the theoretical side of programming, so if someone could walk me through it that would be amazing.

This is my function:

```
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T &e) {
    if(vsize + 1 > capacity)
        allocate_new();
    array[vsize] = e;
    vsize++;
}
```

and this is my `allocate_new` function:

```
void Vector<T>::allocate_new() {
    capacity = vsize * 4;
    T* tmp = new T[capacity];

    for(int i = 0; i < vsize; i++)
        tmp[i] = array[i];

    delete[] array;
    array = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for [cs.se].

Comment: yes, answered here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that as the storage gets larger, a copy takes 4 times as long, but happens only 1/4<sup>th</sup> as often. The 4 and 1/4<sup>th</sup> cancel so you end up with (amortized) constant time.

Ignoring the precise factor you've chosen, in the long term you get O(N * 1/N) = O(1) -> amortized constant time.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert `N` elements into the array, the array has to resize at each power of 4. The amount of time taken to resize at size `4^i` is `O(4^i)`. And similarly, the maximum resize is done at size `N`. So the total amount taken is:

```
T = 1 + 4 + 16 + ... + 4^x
```

where `4^x <= N`. Thus `T=O(4^x)=O(N)`. Thus the average time for each insert operation is on `O(1)`.